# is it possible triggering a contract on specific date?

Tags: contract-development, contract-deployment, datetime

Can I trigger a smart contract on specific date? If I deploy a contract today and I want execute some function of that contract tomorrow without any exteral intervention. Is it possible?

Comment: Depends on your definition for *external intervention*.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible for a Smart Contract to trigger itself.
However, you could use an external service like the [Ethereum Alarm Clock](https://www.ethereum-alarm-clock.com/) which will trigger the Contract for you.

Comment: can you share some code snippet of how can I use EAC for scheduling transaction on specific date?

Comment: Does EAC scheduler continuously  use gas to run?

Comment: The duplicate answer link has a good explanation, alternativly, the development team has a very good description with code examples in their wiki: 
https://ethereum-alarm-clock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#scheduling-your-first-transaction